# Defining a function that only takes in a string literal - to be passed to a macro

Tags: c++, formatting, macros

I'm writing a C++ program that makes use of a C library. The C library has a logging system with a macro that looks like that at its core:

```c
#define MACRO(s, ...) printf("log: " s "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

// supposed to be called like:
MACRO("network error %d", errno)
```

As you can see, the first argument of the macro can only be a string literal, because the expansion will paste the two literals together. The following wouldn't work:

```cpp
char msg[] = "network error %d";
MACRO(msg, errno); // syntax error!
```

I wanted to write a function that wraps some repetitive work I was doing (check the error code, if an error, log it and throw. But I wasn't able to get something much nicer than the following:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>

void throw_on_err(err_t err, const char *format...) {
  if (err != OK) {
    char buffer[128];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, args);
    va_end(args);
    MACRO("%s", buffer);
    throw std::runtime_error(buffer);
  }
}

// supposed to be called like:
throw_on_err(errno, "network error");
```

But this has a couple of issues: it artificially limits the error message size, and the work of `(vsn)printf` is done twice.

Now, I know I could replace `throw_on_err` with a macro, but I'd like to avoid that solution: it's harder to debug, and type safety is poorer. I want to use the library's macro, because it's standard and does more work than what I've shown (work that isn't relevant for the problem at hand, like adding color to the output, checking the log level, etc). I tried to juggle with `const char*` params, `constexpr` functions, but to no avail.

Comment: You are already using variadic arguments already so you are pretty much deep in the waters as far as type safety is concerned.

Comment: That `char buffer[128]` is just begging for a buffer overflow issue... make it at least `char buffer[1000]`. You don't save much by trying to be tight on stack memory.

Comment: You can't pass a string literal through a function, a macro is the only way. Alternatively just ditch the C macro and write the equivalent code in your function

Comment: @selbie vsnprintf isn't going to overflow. I'm developing for an embedded system. I don't have 1000 bytes of stack to go around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I'd just do this:

```
void throw_on_err(int err, const std::string& message)
{
    if (err != 0)
    {
        MACRO("%s", message.c_str());
        throw std::runtime_error(message);
    }
}
```

And that easily facilitates your basic case:

```
throw_on_err(errno, "network error");
```

And it also works if someone wants to jam additional arguments into it by just doing inline string concatenation.

```
const char* reason = getLastError();
throw_on_err(errno, std::string("network error: ") + reason);
```

If you got to have variadic arguments for your log function, consider moving away printf style variading args with a leading format string. And consider just having a variadic template function declared in a header file:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void throw_on_err_impl(std::ostringstream& ss, int argIndex, const T& t)
{
    if (argIndex > 0)
    {
        ss << " ";
    }
    ss << t;
    MACRO("%s", ss.str().c_str());
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
}

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
void throw_on_err_impl(std::ostringstream& ss, int argIndex, const T& t, Rest... rest)
{
    if (argIndex > 0)
    {
        ss << " ";
    }
    ss << t;
    throw_on_err_impl(ss, argIndex+1, rest...);
}


template<typename... Args>
void throw_on_err(int errorCode, Args... args)
{ 
    if (errorCode == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::ostringstream ss;
    throw_on_err_impl(ss, 0, args...);
}

// this single parameter overload is optional.
inline void throw_on_err(int errorCode)
{
    throw_on_err(errorCode, "generic error");
}
```

Then the above can be invoked in any sort of ways:

Simply as:

```
throw_on_err(errno, "network error");
```

Or something like this:

```
std::string host = "www.stackoverflow.com";
std::string internalErrorReason = "tls handshake failure";
int internalStep = 9;
throw_on_err(errno, "network error:", internalErrorReason, "internal step:", internalStep);
```

Comment: In C++17 with fold expression, recursion might be replaced by `std::ostringstream ss; const char* sep = ""; (((ss << sep << args), sep = " "), ...);` (which also handle empty pack).

Comment: It would be preferrable to use `MACRO("%s", std::move(ss).str().c_str());`: In C++20 an optimized overload of the `str()` member function could be used and it doesn't hurt in older C++ versions.

Comment: I'd normally pass a `std::string_view` here, rather than requiring construction of a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom string type that can be concatenated via `+` operator and allows for implicit conversion to `char const*`, and pass this type to the function. This allows you to pass `+arg+` as parameter to the macro.

> But this has a couple of issues: it artificially limits the error message size, and the work of (vsn)printf is done twice.

There's absolutely no way of determining the required buffer size at compile time regardless of the amount of information you have about the format string. The reason for this is the possibility of the format string containing `%s` and the corresponding parameter having type `char const*`; there's simply no way of determining the string length in that case without inspecting the contents of the C-style string. One way or another you need to do dynamic memory allocation for the output to be stored, whether you're using `printf` style functionality or not.

I'd recommend going with C++ writing to a `std::ostream`.

```
template<class T>
concept ostream_writable = requires(T t, std::ostream & s)
{
    {s << t};
};

class throw_on_err
{
    std::optional<std::ostringstream> m_errorReporter;
public:
    throw_on_err(int errorCode)
    {
        if (errorCode != 0)
        {
            m_errorReporter.emplace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * the destructor is responsible for throwing the exception
     */
    ~throw_on_err() noexcept(false)
    {
        if (m_errorReporter.has_value())
        {
            auto const message = std::move(m_errorReporter.value()).str();
            MACRO("%s", message.c_str());
            throw std::runtime_error(message);
        }
    }

    // helper functions for constructing the error step by step
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept
    {
        return m_errorReporter.has_value();
    }

    bool operator!() const noexcept
    {
        return !m_errorReporter.has_value();
    }

    // stream operator

    template<ostream_writable Arg>
    friend throw_on_err& operator<<(throw_on_err& s, Arg&& arg)
    {
        if (s.m_errorReporter.has_value())
        {
            s.m_errorReporter.value() << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
        }
        return s;
    }

    template<ostream_writable Arg>
    friend throw_on_err& operator<<(throw_on_err&& s, Arg&& arg)
    {
        if (s.m_errorReporter.has_value())
        {
            s.m_errorReporter.value() << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    try
    {
        throw_on_err(1) << "network error";
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception caught: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    try
    {
        throw_on_err(0) << "no error";
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception caught: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    try
    {
        throw_on_err err(2);
        if (err)
        {
            err << "some other info we want to add: "
                << "foo bar";
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception caught: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

Btw: Here's an example for the solution mentioned at the start of the answer. As mentioned you won't be able to satisfy all your requirement with this kind of approach either...

```
template<size_t N>
struct FixedSizeString
{
    char m_value[N];

    constexpr FixedSizeString()
        : m_value{}
    {}

    constexpr FixedSizeString(char const(&value)[N])
        : m_value{}
    {
        std::copy(value, value + N, m_value);
    }
    
    constexpr operator char const*() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

};

template<size_t N, size_t M>
constexpr auto operator+(char const (&s1)[N], FixedSizeString<M> const& s2)
{
    FixedSizeString<N + M - 1> result;
    std::copy(
        s2.m_value,
        s2.m_value + M,
        std::copy(s1, s1 + (N - 1), result.m_value)
    );
    return result;
}

template<size_t N, size_t M>
constexpr auto operator+(FixedSizeString<N> const& s1, char const (&s2)[M])
{
    FixedSizeString<N + M - 1> result;
    std::copy(
        s2,
        s2 + M,
        std::copy(s1.m_value, s1.m_value + (N - 1), result.m_value)
    );
    return result;
}

#define MACRO(s, ...) printf("log: " s "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

template<size_t N, class...Args>
void f(FixedSizeString<N> const& format, Args...args)
{
    MACRO(+format+, args...);
}

template<size_t N, class...Args>
void f(char const (&format)[N], Args...args)
{
    MACRO(+FixedSizeString(format)+, args...);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr char const Format[] = "This is a message: \"%\"";
    f(Format, "Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The general rules of thumb in C++ are:

1. **avoid preprocessor macros**:

We have **template**s, **constexpr** and **inline**ing constructs - and more - in C++. Most conventional use-cases of macros are covered by these modern constructs.

2. **avoid `printf` family**:

The `printf` family of functions is prone to lots run-time errors due to programmer fault. In modern C++, `std::format` and `std::format_to` from `<format>` provide type-safe alternatives with compile-time error-detection capabilities.

3. **avoid C style variadic functions**:

In presence of **C++ variadic templates**, support for C style variadic functions is just a backward compatibility feature not intended for newer code. Instead just use **variadic templates** when necessary.

Putting it together, I'd write:

```
#include <format>
#include <concept>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string_view>
#include <system_error>

void throw_prompt(std::runtime _error const err){
    std::cerr << std::string_view{err.what();} << "\n";
    throw err;
};// ver1

void throw_prompt(int val, std::string_view msg){
    throw_prompt(
         std::format("{:d}:\t {:s}", val, msg)
    );
};// ver2

void throw_prompt(std::errc err){
    auto const std::error_condition ec{err};
    throw_prompt(ec.value(), ec.message());
}; //ver3
```

Now use them like:

```
// call ver3:
throw_prompt(std::errc::connection_aborted);
// call ver2:
throw_prompt(4000, std::format("custom err with {}, and {}", 1, 2));
// call ver1:
throw_prompt(std::format("custom err with {}, and {}", 3, 4));
```

Variadic template version seems unnecessary to define but it would use `std::format_string` as 1st argument. For ambiguity issues, this one has a different name:

```
//variadic version:
template<typename ... targs>
void throw_prompt_var(std::format_string<targs> const fmt, targs&& ... vargs){
     throw_prompt(std::format(fmt,std::forward<targs>(vargs) ...);
};
```

And:

```
throw_prompt_var("error {:d}:\t {:s}", 4000, "Custom error");
```